# How to remove the \n, \t and spaces between the strings in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

How do you remove the \n, \t and spaces between strings in java?

Comment: What does *'between the strings'* mean? Could you post an example?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

> \s    A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

[`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has all the predefined classes.

Comment: how to remove only \n \t not spaces

Comment: the same way, but using `\\n+\\t+` instead

Comment: But note that `\\n+\\t+` only matches new lines followed by tabs. Probably `[\t\n]+` is meant...

Answer (score 7):

Use [String.replaceAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a regular expression to remove all whitespace:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```