# Android - Put method of JSONObect add a '\' when find a '/' in a string

Tags: android, json

I have to send an encrypted password with DES to a WebServer using a JSONObject encapsulated in a POST request. The problem is that, when I do this:

```
JSONObject jsonLogin = new JSONObject();
try{
    jsonLogin.put("username", usernameS);
    jsonLogin.put("password", passwordEncrypted);
}catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I print the content of the JSON object with:

```
System.out.println("JSON to Server = "+jsonLogin);
```

the result is:

```
JSON to Server = {"password":"Qxw\/h16PVdE=\n","username":"XXXXXXXX@gmail.com"}
```

but the correct password is `Qxw/h16PVdE=`,so the Server doesn't recognize it.

I found some suggestion that indicate to use: `string.replaceAll("\/","/");` 
But I would like to implement a clean solution.
Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Who adds the "\n" at the end of the password?

Comment: I have just see the "\n".. is the put method that add '\' and also '\n'. The content of passwordEncrypted is: Qxw/h16PVdE=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are doing something wrong while encrypting the data. Any way you can use this piece of code to manipulate the string after encryption.

```
String encryptedPassword = (String) jsonLogin.get("password");
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(encryptedPassword) && encryptedPassword.endsWith("\n")) {
    encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword.substring(0, encryptedPassword.length() - 1);
    jsonLogin.put("password", encryptedPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer

[How to remove the \n, \t and spaces between the strings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461331/how-to-remove-the-n-t-and-spaces-between-the-strings-in-java)

You can call `passwordEncrypted.replaceAll("\\n+", "");` before writing value.

Comment: Thanks Arie I do some try and you have reason, the "\n" is in passwordEncrypted but "passwordEncrypted.replaceAll("\\n+", "");" dosn't delete it

Comment: Using this: passwordEncrypted = passwordEncrypted.substring(0, passwordEncrypted.length()-1); remove the \n correctly!