# How to remove the space and "\n" only in both ends

Tags: java, regex, string, whitespace

I have read the thread of 
[How to remove the \n, \t and spaces between the strings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461331/how-to-remove-the-n-t-and-spaces-between-the-strings-in-java)

But I hope to reserve the space or \n in the middle, so that at last I will check every split the elements by space or \n as  commands.

And something is even more,for example. If the user enter `\n command1\n command2 \n`(and the command may be more than twice or only once). I hope to get the String as `command1 command2`.

It will be great that if the \n in the middle will be all replaced as white space since after that, I will only need to NEWSTRING.split(" ") to get all the command. But it is ok to keep the '\n'(mutiple times) inside

So, if the string is splited by \n or space, I just hope to keep the space, but if there are \n(perhaps multiple times), it is ok to keep them in the middle.

In conclusion, I hope my String will be formated as "some string"+[space or \n] +""some string".

If the Regrex can not help me, any good way to do that? Thank you very much!

More example:

The reason I do this is that I hope to understand what command user is exactly speaking. For example, he may say " 1 " which means only "1", and he may says"\n1\n apple\n "which means "1 apple".

Comment: so the str.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); is not working?

Comment: First clarify your question.. Whether you want `\n` between 2 space separated strings or not? . *If the user enter "\nabc\n de \n". I hope to get the String as "abc de".*. *but if there are \n(perhaps multiple times), it is ok to keep them in the middle.* are opposite of each other.

Comment: Seems to me that you want trim() function of String

Comment: you mean this `System.out.println("\nabc\n de \n".replaceAll("\\n", ""));`

Comment: `\n` + space -> space and space + `\n` -> "" Why so?

Comment: @TheLostMind , yes , I have explained more details about that, it is ok to keep that since I will split the command list at last.

Comment: In this `\ncommand1\n command2 \n`, you want double spaces at the center?

Comment: @AvinashRaj , I don't care how many the \n or space inside, because I will at last split it. I just do not hope the \n or space to corrupt my logic of understanding what user is speaking.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? What's wrong with a loop?

Comment: @gtgaxiola No, that dosen't work at all. trim can not even remove the "\n" in both ends, not to mention that I just want only one space or "\n" inside my string

Comment: for example if the word is `\n \n foo bar \n bar foo \n\n`, then how we find the center?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `\n` in your string with a space , then trim your string :

```
String str="\\n command1\\n command2 \\n";
String formattedStr=str.replaceAll("\\\\n"," ").trim();// formattedStr='command1 command2'
```

Comment: But I tried "String formattedStr=str.replaceAll("\n"," ").trim();" , it works ok, why did you use replaceAll("\\\\n"," ") ?

Comment: yes, if you set str value to "\n command1\n command2 \n" it would work as you say.

Comment: But if the user is typing "\"+"\n", I should respect them as "\"+"n" rather than a new line. So, what I mean is replace the new line and the white space, I guess you misunderstand me but anyway, you answer helps!