# What's the best way to remove all \n \r \t from a string?

Tags: java, carriage-return

What's the best way to remove all `\n`, `\r`, `\t` from a `String` in `java`?
Is there some sort of `library` and `method` that can do that for me nicely instead of me having to use `string.replaceAll();` multiple times?

Comment: Why multiple times? The parameter to `replaceAll` is a regular expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove the \n, \t and spaces between the strings in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461331/how-to-remove-the-n-t-and-spaces-between-the-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

Please try this:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\t]+", "");
```

Comment: The answer of @morels is more elegant than mine, but it will also replace whitespace (which is not specified to be removed in the question). My solution focus on replacing \n \r \t only. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do `str.replaceAll` multiple times.
Just use a regex:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: This will also remove `\x0B` and `\f` as well as whitespace, so might be too much of a sledgehammer approach if those characters are required...

Comment: remove singular characters as well, `str.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\t]+", "");` like @Tsung-Ting Kuo does

Comment: Maybe replace such a sequence with a single space, otherwise the text is squashed. And end with a `.trim()`

Answer (score 2):

Using regex in java. for future reference, if you want to replace a more complex subset of strings

```
// strings that you want to remove
String regexp = "str1|str2|str3";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);

// here input is your input string
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
m.appendTail(sb);


System.out.println(sb.toString());
```